# How to mask targeted MovieClips with ActionScript 2.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

The following script generates snowflakes:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var t:MovieClip = snow_mc.duplicateMovieClip("snow" + i, i);
    t._x = random(750);
    t._y = random(550);
    t._xscale = t._yscale = random(80) + 20;
    t.gotoAndPlay(Math.round(random(81) + 1));
}
```

I want the snowflakes to appear under a mask whose instance name is mask_mc:

```
_root.setMask(mask_mc);
```

But my mask cuts all my layers and my background image. I want it to only cut my snowflakes.

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't apply your mask to the `_root`, but to an `empty MovieClip` where your snow will be created (AS Linkage Snow):

```
var box:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("box", 0); 
var t:MovieClip;

for (var i:Number = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    t = box.attachMovie("Snow", "snow", i);
    t._x = Math.random() * 750;
    t._y = Math.random() * 550;
    t._xscale = t._yscale = Math.random() * 80 + 20;
    t.gotoAndPlay(Math.round(Math.random() * 81 + 1));
}

box.setMask(mask_mc);
```

Comment: Sorry but your code I have does not work .
Why is this line in capital letters "S"                   `t = box.attachMovie("Snow", "snow", i);` ?

Comment: @Александр Гришин Snow is the AS Linkage of your `class` Snow. By convention, all class names begin with a capital letter. Right-click the image in the library, select `Properties`, `Export for ActionScript` and `Export in first Frame` and type `Snow` in the Identifier text box.

Comment: Yes) Snow work, mask does not work. I type 'box' in the Identifier text box (in the library,Properties).

Comment: @Александр Гришин AS Linkage of your class `Snow`: type `Snow` in the Identifier text box (library, Properties).

Comment: Yes,yes i type 'Snow' and i see this [ https://yadi.sk/i/NMYOIOyKddWtf ] and the need to this [ https://yadi.sk/i/aUqCeK07ddX48 ]

Comment: Александр Гришин `mask_mc` appears because it isn't recognized by the code. Verify you have a MovieClip called `mask_mc` on your scene.